# is there a method to process dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe llike :

```
words ; in ; region1 ; region2
mars ; france ; marseille 3 ; marseille 1
lil ; france; lille 
marig ; italy; marseille 3 ; nantes 3
```

i want to have in output :

```
regions ; words_list ; in_list
marseille 3 ; ["mars","marig"] ; ["france","italy"]
marseille 1 ; ["mars"] ; ["france"]
lille ; ['lil'] ; ['france']
nantes 3; ["marig"] ; ['italy']
```

so i want to regroup data / region (region 1 or 2)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assume df is your dataframe. I think you can get the desired output if you use this :

Group by region1 (then region2) and get the list of values for both columns 'words' and 'in'

```
output_1 = df.groupby('region1').agg({'words': lambda x: list(x), 'in' : lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
output_2 = df.groupby('region2').agg({'words': lambda x: list(x), 'in' : lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
```

Concat results for the column region1 and region2

```
output = pd.concat(output_1, output_2)
```

Rename the columns

```
 output.columns = ['regions', 'words_list', 'in_list']
```